# VLC Media Player display problems

Tags: vlc, media

I installed VLC media player 2.2.0-pre2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.0-pre1-15-g5178b24). When I'm on normal view there's a random green line displaying at bottom, right, and left.

Even if Im on full screen mode the green line is still displaying. I used to play 720p and 1080p videos. Im using gnome 14.04 LTS

Comment: mark the answer as definitive please

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem, go into the settings and disable hardware acceleration, after that you won't have any annoying green lines.[image]

Comment: It works bud! I can watch videos now, without that annoying line.

Comment: I had to reset VLC after disabling acceleration. Now it works great!

Comment: Glad it worked.